# How to Remove Custom Layout Updates in One Go

Tags: layout

On products I set custom product updates I also did on catogories pages, but now I need to remove them because this is interfering with my new theme...

Product;
Page Layout - 2 columns with left bar

Catogories;
Page Layout - 2 columns with left bar

I need to remove these updates on all..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For products you can use the "Update attributes" mass action ("Select all" selects all products, not only the currently visible page):

[image: screenshot 1]

Then update the page layout to "No layout update":

[image: screenshot 2]